What is the meaning of どうだ in this sentence?
I am reading One Piece volume 51 and one of the characters dialogue goes like this (he has a weird way of speaking for some reason):

この海の片田舎で...しがねェマフィアをやってたんだよ
村の住人連をオドし回って暮らす...それなりに幸せな人生だった...

Fairly easy to understand. But on the next page he continues:

それがどうだ...ある日突然現れたレベル違いの海兵達。
背中に大きな”逃げ傷”を受け...世間にゃ二度とツラを晒せず鉄仮面.

What does それがどうだ mean? It does not seem it is being used in the questioning way for "how is that?

This それが is where the nuance of "however" is added. It's a common expression used to introduce a contrasting turn of events, and you shouldn't parse this が as an ordinary subject marker. See the last part of this answer.
どうだ on the other hand conveys the nuance of "so what?", "you know what" or "can you believe?". It indicates something surprising follows. When combined, それがどうだ functions as a lead-in to something unexpected and undesirable.

Wow, I never thought to search それが because I thought the meaning was obvious, I have never seen that meaning before...
To help me grasp that nuance of どうだ. Is the intended meaning from 如何?
